# In SWIG , how can i use int * variable without typemaps.i

Tags: python, c, swig

I have a program where in a C function somewhat like below code. When i try to call this function via python it it throwing error saying

argument 2 of type 'int *'.  In swig i saw there is way to handle this that is via typemaps is there any other way other typemaps. As there are bunch of functions with numerous arguments having int * .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check(int k, int *i) {
  if( k%2 == 0) 
    *i = 1;
  else 
    *i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typemaps are really the way SWIG handles all types, but if you don't want `typemaps.i` specifically, then how about:

```
%module x

%include <cpointer.i>
%pointer_functions(int,int)

%inline %{

void check(int k, int *i) {
  if (k % 2 == 0) 
    *i = 1;
  else 
    *i = 0;
}

%}
```

`cpointer.i` lets you create simple pointers to a type.  Here's an example of use:

```
>>> import x
>>> i=x.new_int()
>>> x.check(6,i)
>>> x.int_value(i)
1
>>> x.delete_int(i)
```

But really, it is simpler to use `typemaps.i`.  Below `%apply` applies the predefined `OUTPUT` typemap, declaring that all future `int *` parameters are output parameters.  Python will not require the parameter for the call, and will return the parameter as an output instead.  The normal return value and all output parameters are returned using a tuple if necessary.

```
%module x

%include <typemaps.i>
%apply int *OUTPUT { int * };

%inline %{

void check(int k, int *i) {
  if (k % 2 == 0) 
    *i = 1;
  else 
    *i = 0;
}

%}
```

Use example:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.check(5)
0
>>> x.check(6)
1
```

Comment: Hi Mark,
    As per your suggestion i am using typemaps. but even in typemaps i am unable to achieve following scenario ..

int f_name(int *k)
normall in C in that function f_name it gets filled up and will return some value...... but here even using typemaps i am unable to achieve that way , it is returning that filled value as a list (eg: [<ret val>, <fill_val>] ) instead of filling value k.

Comment: Python can't modify an integer because it is immutable.  That's why it returns the output parameter as a tuple.  Call it like: `ret,k = f_name(k)`.